# The (Hecke) double coset von Neumann algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, von-neumann-algebras, hecke-algebras, hypergroups

It it well-known in the von Neumann algebra theory that for $\Gamma$ a non-trivial countable group, the von Neumann algebra $L(\Gamma)$ generating by $\Gamma$ acting by left multiplication on $l^2(\Gamma)$, is a ${\rm II}_1$ factor iff $\Gamma$ is an [ICC group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_conjugacy_class_property).

Now let $(G \subset \Gamma)$ be an inclusion of a *finite* group $G$ in a countable group $\Gamma$, Let $\mathbb{C}(G \backslash \Gamma /  G) $ be the (Hecke) double coset algebra: the subalgebra of $\mathbb{C}G $, generated by the elements $a_{\gamma} = \sum_{\alpha \in G \gamma G} \alpha$ (well-defined because $G$ finite) with $\gamma \in \Gamma$.  Let $L(\Gamma,G)$ be the von Neumann algebra generated by $\mathbb{C}(G \backslash \Gamma /  G) $ acting by left multiplication on $l^2(G \backslash \Gamma)$.

*Question*: What's the necessary and sufficient condition on $(G \subset \Gamma)$ for  $L(\Gamma,G)$ to be a ${\rm II}_1$ factor?

In the case that there are inclusions $(G \subset \Gamma)$ with $\Gamma$ ICC, $G \neq \{ e \}$ and $L(\Gamma,G)$ ${\rm II}_1$ factor:
*Optional question 1*:   Is it true that $L(\Gamma,G) \simeq L(\Gamma)$?

*Optional question 2*: How to generalize the construction above for $G$ infinite?

Comment: Are the tags 'hypergroups' and 'harmonic-analysis' really relevant to this question?

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: The double coset algebra $\mathbb{C}(G \backslash \Gamma /  G) $ is an example of hypergroup.  All the objects of the post are close to noncommutative harmonic analysis, so an harmonic analyst could answer such questions or at least being interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$L(\Gamma,G)$ is the algebra of endomorphisms of the representation $l^2( \Gamma/G)$ (with $\Gamma$ acting by left multiplication). This answer your second optional question. Also, by classical results on $W^*$-categories, the category of normal representations of $L(\Gamma,G)$ will be equivalent to the category of unitary representations of $G$ that are retract of sums of copies of $l^2(\Gamma /G)$, which generally allow to determine the type in concrete situations but I don't know what a general criterion would be. In fact, in the general case this algebra can also be of type $III$ which make me think there is no simple criterion.

In the special case where $G$ is finite, $l^2(\Gamma /G)$ is a retract of $l^2(\Gamma)$ hence $L(\Gamma,G)$ is a corner of $L(\Gamma)$. If in addition $\Gamma$ is ICC, then $L(\Gamma)$ is a factor and hence any non trivial corner will be Morita equivalent to $L(\Gamma)$. So $L(\Gamma,G)$ will be Morita equivalent to $L(\Gamma)$ and hence of the same type.

Also note that in this situation $L(\Gamma)$ and $L(\Gamma,G)$ will often be isomorphic, but by a "non natural" isomorphism which will not going to be compatible with the natural Morita equivalence...

Comment: By the same type, I meant type $II$, but it is also easy to check that it is type $II_1$ either because $l^2(\Gamma/G)$ is finitely generated as a $L^2(G)$ module or by constructing a trace explicitely.

Comment: Thank you! I note the typo that sometimes you have written $L^2(\Gamma)$ instead of $L(\Gamma)$.

Comment: What's your type ${\rm III}$ examples?

Comment: That's corrected thanks ^^
For the type III exemple you have the original construction of Bost-Connes system as a Hecke algebra which if I remeber correctly gives a type III von Neuman algebra if one takes the completion (see the 1994 paper of Bost & Connes). But maybe there is simpler exemple.